# nginx vhost error : static files not found

Tags: nginx, vhosts

I have a vhost who has problem serving static files : 
`http://graphite.domain.fr/static/img/carbon-fiber.png  404`

**graphite.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name graphite.domain.fr;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /opt/graphite/webapp/content;

    location /media/ {
      root /opt/graphite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin;
    }

    auth_basic "Area 51, password please!";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/ansible/grafana/.htpasswd;

    location / {

        if ($http_origin ~* (http://graphite.domain.fr)) {
            set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($cors = 'true') {
            add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;    
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";         
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS";
            add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";
        }

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

The images are in the right folder, with correct chmod (644) readable by `www-data` :

[image]

**What might be the cause ? All resources under /static/ url gives me 404 error**

Comment: Should `http://graphite.domain.fr/static/img/carbon-fiber.png` actually be reachable to us, or is that just an example? Can you locally access that content via HTTP (ie, `http://localhost/......`)?

Comment: It's just an example, it should be reachable to me with the right domain name, but it gives me also a 404. The image have 644 chmod and is readable by www-data

Comment: Your screencap of the `content` folder also isn't enough to speculate (is the `png` actually in `img`, and does the `png` have sufficient permissions?). You've at least narrowed it to an issue with the webserver itself. Are there ANY resources available to you, or just items within the `img` folder?

Comment: Yeah, some content is available to me, but not all file with url begining with /static/. The image is present, have correct chmod and have correct format ;)

Comment: Ok. Good luck, wish I knew what was going on!